# Boolean data being passed as blank in Angular / HTTP POST request

Tags: angular, http-post

I am trying to post some data to an API, and my boolean data keeps showing up as blank. Does anyone have any thoughts as to what may be causing this?

```
const notifications: Array<Notification> = [
    {
        id: "all",
        title: "All",
        isActive: false
    }
 ];
```

Here is my `interface` for the data:

```
export interface Notification {
    id: string,
    title: string,
    isActive: boolean
}
```

Now, when I attempt to pass this data through a *HTTP POST* request, it shows up as:

```
notifications: [
    {
        "id": "all",
        "title": "All",
        "isActive": ""
    }
 ];
```

I am noticing that the `isActive` property is blank when I inspect the `http.post()` call through Safari/Chrome, which is causing issues in my API, as the data is appearing to be blank versus a boolean value.

Here is how I am passing the data to the API:

```
this.http.post('/api/', {notifications: notifications}).subscribe((res:any) => {
    console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: what is your code while passing the data to api?

Comment: @jaysurya - I have updated the original question with that example.

Comment: this code will not modify your data. Are you sure the notifications object in the above  snippet is as expected?

Comment: I do add a `Content-Type: application/json` to all of the http requests through an interceptor, that's about all I can think of.

Comment: false might be converted to "false", but not "". Has to be some other code that causes it. debug it with console.log

Comment: post api data you are sending please serialize it as json ,use JSON.stringify() to serialize and then check if it still coming might be when notification is forming at that time code has some issue better to provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Before sending transform boolean value toString
Like `isActive.toString()`

So before making api you could do

```
notifications = {...notifications, isActive: notifications.isActive.toString() };
```